# Where is an object file for 'stdio.h' in Windows?

Tags: stdio, object-files, c-standard-library

I use Windows and Visual Studio 10.0 now.

I was wondering where the object files for C standard library functions declared in stdio.h, string.h, etc. are located in Windows, so searched for an object file for 'stdio.h' but failed.

As below,

[Files in library folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6g8vI.png)

These are all in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\lib.

Which one is the object file for 'stdio.h'?
Or is the object file for 'stdio.h' in another path?

Are there the object files for C standard library only in that path?

Answer (score 0):

That header declares functions that are part of the C standard library so they are found in the different libc* files (static linking) or msvcrt* files (dynamic linking). MT is multithreaded, D is debug.

See [Microsoft's documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/154753).

Comment: Thanks for replying and the link. I understood about static and dynamic linking due to your comment.
But about the last question, does the path of 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\lib' have 'all' object files for C standard library? or are those object files spread around in different paths?

Answer (score 0):

If you've used MingGW installation manager, you may check at C:\MinGW\include. For me it's there.